# Can we use Statamic CMS ( as a backend) and Vue with GraphQL on the frontend for the website?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, graphql, statamic

I want to build a portal in which I want to have below stacks:

1. Statamic CMS (As the backend)
2. GraphQL for the API's
3. Vue js as the frontend

Can anyone help me with the above tech stack, and it will be helpful if there will be any documentation available to develop a website with these stacks.

Thanks!!

I have gone through the documentation of Statamic in which I am confused that I can have all in statamic or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Statamic has built-in support for GraphQL. There's documentation on how the [GraphQL API works here](https://statamic.dev/graphql#content).

Statamic doesn't care what you're using to consume the GraphQL API (you could use Vue/React/Vanilla/whatever you want).

Comment: Hey @McClean

Thanks for the response.

Still, I am confused if we can make a dynamic website using Statamic or it can handle only content-based website?

As I am planning to build a gaming website in which there will be multiple options will be available at the backend to control the frontend. 

Can you please suggestion if Statamic can handle it?

Comment: Absolutely, Statamic can handle that. You can configure the fields you'd like to be managed within the CMS - they'll all then be available for you in GraphQL.